# iOS: how to post to Facebook with the contents of a label, rather than static text

Tags: facebook, post, label, integration

I have an iOS project, where I have on a .xib page, a column of Labels consisting of text, and to the right of which, are a set of play buttons to play each audio, such as in the .m code:

```
-(IBAction)pushButton {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mysound" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if(theAudio)[theAudio release];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    theAudio.volume = 1.0;
    [theAudio play];
}
```

To the right of the play button, I have a Post to Facebook button. I know that I can easily post static text to Facebook like so:

```
-(IBAction)ShareFB1 {
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    slComposeViewController = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [slComposeViewController setInitialText:@"My static text that has the contents of the label manually entered"];
    [slComposeViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]];
    [self presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Facebook Account" message:@"There are no Facebook accounts confiured, configure or create accounts in Settings." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
}
```

What I would like to do, is when the play button is pressed, I want to assign a variable to be equal to the text that is in the associated label.  I imagine that should be easy enough.  Then, I want to get rid of the individual Post to Facebook buttons to the right of the Play buttons, and I want to have an app bar button for single button access to post to Facebook, with the contents of the label, which would be assigned to the variable when one hits the play button.  Having one Facebook button means having to dynamically assign the text to the variable be posted.

Does anyone know how to configure the code to post the contents of a label, or a variable, rather than static text?  I have searched for a way to do this, but have not been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using:

```
[slComposeViewController setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your text no.%d here: %@",yourCounter, yourLabel.text]];
```

EDIT:

```
NSString  *posttofacebooktext=[mylabelname text];
[slComposeViewController setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posting to Facebook: %@", posttofacebooktext]];
```

Comment: Thanks Anoop!  I will give it a shot! In my case, I may just need myLabel.text if I understand that correctly.  Since I have several labels on the same page, I still need to figure out how to tell my (IBAction)pushButton to assign the label to a variable.

Comment: What to figure out? *assign the label to a variable* ? whats a big deal here?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I think first, I need to assign a name to the label. I assume this is done in the Identity Inspector when the label itself is highlighted, under the Document section, in the box to the right of Label.  Assume I put "mylabelname" in this field.  Then, I think have to add it to the IBAction pushbutton method, maybe something like this:
posttofacebooktext = mylabelname.text;  - then, I could use in my setInitialText something like this: NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posting to Facebook: %@", posttofacebooktext]];   - am I close?  Thanks!  Rob

Comment: yes that is called IBOutlet-used to access the values, and the method that act on button click is IBAction. :)

Comment: Thanks Anoop, any chance you may have a snippet of a code example?  I don't think my syntax is accurate, but I am still trying to get it right.  Thanks! Rob

Comment: Thanks Anoop, the only other thing I need to figure out is how to configure the posttofacebooktext to be a NSString or a NSMutableString in the IBAction pushbutton.  I appreciate the help a lot, thanks!  -Rob

Comment: Thanks, should this: NSString  *posttofacebooktext=[mylabelname text];  - actually be "mylabelname.text"?  Or is the space okay and no dot is needed?  Also, I assume that this NSString declaration should be in the IBAction pushbutton - this looks pretty good!   Have to step away from the project for a few hours, but this looks like it will fit the bill. I will mark this as answered - thanks!

Comment: either `[mylabelname text]` or `mylabelname.text` Both are same. First in Obj-C syntax next in dot syntax as in C.